# C# função no controller receber um array

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, array

Preciso pegar um array de select e enviar para uma funçao no controller, porem ela sempre chega como null, mesmo enviando o array completo. Segue abaixo o código:
Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult GetLocais(int [] idcTipoLocal)
    {
        var local = context.Locais.Where(x => x.IdcSite == ContextSession.UsuarioLogado.IdcSite && x.Status /*&& x.IdcTipoLocal == idcTipoLocal*/).Distinct()
               .Select(x => new { id = x.IdcLocal, text = x.Nome }).OrderBy(y => y.text).ToList();
        return Json(local, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
 var opt = new Array();
$("#selTipLocal").change(function () {
    var obj = [];
    $('#selTipLocal > option:selected').each(
        function (i) {
            opt[i] = $(this).val();
            opt[i] = parseInt(opt[i]);
        });

    var jsonKey = {
        "idcTipoLocal": opt
    };
    $.get("/relocorrencia/getlocais", jsonKey, function (data) {
        $("#selLocal").multiselect("destroy");
        multiSelectRelOco("selLocal", data);
    });
});
```

Eu ja conferi e o arrey chega ok, mas ao enviar para o controler, idctipolocal sempre chega como null

Comment: Não deveria ser **`$.get("/relocorrencia/getlocais", JSON.stringify(opt), function (data) {`**?

Comment: Mudei e continua chegando null

Comment: Como tá ficando a requisição?

Comment: Tenta `var opt = [];`

Comment: Tenta fazer um `var teste = Request["nomeVariavel"];`. Outra solução seria colocar trocar o parâmetro `int [] idcTipoLocal` por `string idcTipoLocal` e adicionar um parse dentro do controler desse modo: `int[] tipoLocalArr = idcTipoLocal.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Consegui aqui dessa forma:

var opt = new Array();

```
$("#selTipLocal").change(function () {

    $('#selTipLocal > option:selected').each(
        function (i) {
            opt[i] = $(this).val();
            opt[i] = parseInt(opt[i]);
        }
    )
    if (opt[0] != null) {
        var obj = [];
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            traditional: true,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "GET",
            data: { "idcTipoLocal": opt },
            url: "/relocorrencia/getlocais",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                    $("#selLocal").multiselect("destroy");
                    multiSelectRelOco("selLocal", data);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        multiSelectRelOco("selLocal", null);
    }
});
```